# dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath of NSData sometimes works, sometimes has no function

Tags: iphone

I used the codes below to load image file in app bundle.
The codes work! imageData does NOT return 0x0

```
NSMutableString *sss;
sss=[[NSMutableString  alloc] initWithString: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[sss appendString:@"/"] ;
[sss appendString:@"thumbnail.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sss];
```

but the codes below in which almost everything is same have no function, imageData always DOES return 0x0, it looks like [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath ] does not work for large size image file

```
NSMutableString *sss;
sss=[[NSMutableString  alloc] initWithString: [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[sss appendString:@"/"] ;
[sss appendString:@"original.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sss];
```

Both of thumbnail.png and original.png are in the same directory of main bundle.

thumbnail.png

[image: thumbnail.png]

original.png

[image: original.png]

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Marc

Comment: When you say *"Both of thumbnail.png and original.png are in the same directory of main bundle."*, do you mean the actual *.app directory or that you see them both in your Xcode project in the same folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't have anything to do with the size of the file.  Check and see if you've spelled the file name correctly in your code.  The file names are case-sensitive, so if the file is named original.PNG, then you'll need to make sure it is written that way in code as well.

Make sure that the original.png file has been added to your project, and if so, try removing it from your project and re-adding it.  When you drag the file into your project, make sure the option "copy files..." is checked.

Answer (score 1):

check out if it really contains on resource . 
check that file is in: 
Targets/ProductName/Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 1):

I also think that the file has not been added to resources. Check the 'Resources' folder in your xcode project, and if it isnt there, put it in there. Either by dragging it in there, or by rightclicking -> new file.